# How can we re-initialize a thread without killing it?

Tags: c++, unix

Is there any way, by which we can Re-Initialize a thread without killing it. I want to use the existing thread, but they will again start from the beginning.

Comment: Write your thread function so that it returns to the beginning upon receiving a certain message.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by 'thread reinitialization'?

Comment: Please expand your question. Are you after a thread pool type thing? You want to allocate tasks to a thread, and have it go and get the next task? Or you just want to do the same thing again and again? Or do you want it to respond to a request to restart?

Comment: I want it to respond to a restart , currently for every restart , threads are killed and again recreated . But I want to reuse the existing threads by re-initializinig them (i.e. It would clean-up all the resources and start from the beginning). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that manages a thread.
In the run method of this class have it wait until some work is assigned to the class in the form of a function pointer or some other class that implements a "work" interface.

Once work is assigned, the thread can stop waiting and execute the work.
Once the work is complete the thread sits and waits until more work is assigned to it.

This allows you to keep the thread running and waiting for work, without having to recreate it when new work comes along.

Answer (score 1):

What y ou are asking for can only be achieved by the logic of your thread function. The thread library/operating system does not know about your logic and cannot possibly know where you want it to go on *reinitialization*.

Also note that while you can achieve something similar by canceling and starting the thread, thread cancellation is quite often dangerous (you might leak resources) if even possible (thread must hit a cancellation point) and should be avoided in most cases. So you are back at square one: implement logic in the function to detect the event and *restart* with whatever definition of start you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two events: **restart** and **stop**. Your thread function would wait in a loop for any of them. If it detects **restart**, it would perform the task and go back waiting for events. If it detects **stop**, it would simply return.